# The paint method is called again and again and the process is not stopping in Applet and the hex are repainted and i lose all the numbers

Tags: java, applet

I was trying to recreate the catan hexagonal grid and I am new to applet and swing. I am not clear with the concept of paint(). I have found out that graphics method drawPolygon must be used for drawing hexagon and I implemented a grid like structure and the values from the arraylist are populated there and refreshed so I removed them after they are drawn using drawString method causing me index out of bounds and I thought is cause of some other issues. But finally I noticed that the grid is refreshing again and again I am clueless as I do not understand the concept. Since the paint method is called my hexagonal grid is rendered continuously and please check and help me how to effectively correct this issue. I have the method to get the values from the arraylist and populate it in the hexagon grid.

```
    package catan.board.game.utilities;

public class Utilities {

    public static int[] getInitialXPoints(int increment){
        final int[] xPoints = { 0 + increment, 45 + increment, 90 + increment, 90 + increment, 45 + increment,
                0 + increment };
        return xPoints;

    }
    public static int[] getInitialYPoints(int increment){
        final int[] yPoints = { 45 + increment, 0 + increment, 45 + increment, 90 + increment, 135 + increment,
                90 + increment };
        return yPoints;
    }

    public static int[] getMoreXPoints(int[] xPoints, int increment) {
        //System.out.println("The x points before the increment[" + increment + "]-->" + Arrays.toString(xPoints));
        int[] newXPoints = new int[xPoints.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < xPoints.length; i++)
            newXPoints[i] = xPoints[i] + increment;
        //System.out.println("The x points after the increment[" + increment + "]-->" + Arrays.toString(newXPoints));
        return newXPoints;
    }

    public static int[] getMoreYPoints(int[] yPoints, int increment) {
        //System.out.println("The y points before the increment[" + increment + "]-->" + Arrays.toString(yPoints));
        int[] newYPoints = new int[yPoints.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < yPoints.length; i++)
            newYPoints[i] = yPoints[i] + increment;
        //System.out.println("The y points after the increment[" + increment + "]-->" + Arrays.toString(newYPoints));
        return newYPoints;
    }


}


    package catan.board.game;

    import java.applet.Applet;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Polygon;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

    import catan.board.game.utilities.Utilities;

    public class CatanBoardApplet extends Applet {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        static final int HEX_CONSTANT = 840;
        int xOval = 720;
        int yOval = 60;
        int widthOval = 600;
        int heightOval = 600;
        int nPoints = 6;
        int angle = 45;
        int gridSpace = 20;
        int row = 3;
        int maxLength = 5;
        int[] xPoints = Utilities.getInitialXPoints(0);
        int[] yPoints = Utilities.getInitialYPoints(0);

        static ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer> expectedHexValuesMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        static ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer> actualHexValuesMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        static ArrayList<Integer> hexValueList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        @Override
        public void init() {
            System.out.println("Init");
            setHexNumbers();
            Graphics g = getGraphics();
            System.out.println("graphics--->" + g);
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            g.drawString("Welcome to the Dripura's catan game", 200, 20);
            g.draw3DRect(30, 30, 1300, 650, true);
            g.drawOval(xOval, yOval, widthOval, heightOval);
            g.setColor(new Color(42, 179, 231));
            g.fillOval(xOval, yOval, widthOval, heightOval);
            drawHexagonalGrid();
            rollDice();
        }

        private void rollDice() {

            System.out.println("rolldice");

        }

        private static void setHexNumbers() {
            expectedHexValuesMap.put(2, 1);
            expectedHexValuesMap.put(12, 1);
            expectedHexValuesMap.put(3, 2);
            expectedHexValuesMap.put(4, 2);
            expectedHexValuesMap.put(5, 2);
            expectedHexValuesMap.put(6, 2);
            expectedHexValuesMap.put(7, 0);
            expectedHexValuesMap.put(8, 2);
            expectedHexValuesMap.put(9, 2);
            expectedHexValuesMap.put(10, 2);
            expectedHexValuesMap.put(11, 2);

            actualHexValuesMap.put(2, 0);
            actualHexValuesMap.put(12, 0);
            actualHexValuesMap.put(3, 0);
            actualHexValuesMap.put(4, 0);
            actualHexValuesMap.put(5, 0);
            actualHexValuesMap.put(6, 0);
            actualHexValuesMap.put(7, 0);
            actualHexValuesMap.put(8, 0);
            actualHexValuesMap.put(9, 0);
            actualHexValuesMap.put(10, 0);
            actualHexValuesMap.put(11, 0);

            Random r = new Random();
            int min = 2;
            int max = 12;
            while (!expectedHexValuesMap.equals(actualHexValuesMap)) {
                int hexValue = r.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
                System.out.println("value--->" + hexValue);
                if (hexValue != 0 && actualHexValuesMap.get(hexValue) < expectedHexValuesMap.get(hexValue)) {
                    hexValueList.add(hexValue);
                    actualHexValuesMap.put(hexValue, actualHexValuesMap.get(hexValue) + 1);
                }
                System.out.println("actualHexValuesMap: " + actualHexValuesMap);
            }
            System.out.println("hexValueList: " + hexValueList);
            System.out.println("hexValueList size: " + hexValueList.size());

        }

        private void placeNumbers(Graphics g, Polygon p, boolean flag) {
            int x = p.getBounds().x + 30;
            int y = p.getBounds().y + 50;
            int width = p.getBounds().width / 3;
            int height = p.getBounds().width / 3;
            g.drawOval(x, y, width, height);
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            // g.setColor(new Color((int)(Math.random() * 0x1000000)));
            g.fillOval(x, y, width, height);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            System.out.println(hexValueList);
            if (flag) {
                int hexValue = hexValueList.get(0);
                g.drawString("" + hexValue, x + 10, y + 20);
                hexValueList.remove(0);
                flag = false;
            }
        }

        private Graphics drawHexagonalGrid() {
            System.out.println("Drawing the hexagonal grid");
            Graphics g = getGraphics();
            System.out.println("graphics---->" + g);
            Boolean isValidHex = true;
            // row 1 - three grids
            Polygon p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT + 45),
                    Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 20), nPoints);
            //
            g.drawPolygon(p);
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillPolygon(p);
            placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex);
            p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT + 135),
                    Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 20), nPoints);

            g.drawPolygon(p);
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillPolygon(p);
            placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex);
            p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT + 225),
                    Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 20), nPoints);

            g.drawPolygon(p);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillPolygon(p);
            placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex);
            // row 2 - four grids
            p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT + 0),
                    Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 110), nPoints);

            g.drawPolygon(p);
            // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(p.xpoints) + " " +
            // Arrays.toString(p.ypoints));
            g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            g.fillPolygon(p);
            placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex);
            p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT + 90),
                    Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 110), nPoints);

            g.drawPolygon(p);
            // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(p.xpoints) + " " +
            // Arrays.toString(p.ypoints));
            g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
            g.fillPolygon(p);
            placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex);
            p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT + 180),
                    Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 110), nPoints);

            g.drawPolygon(p);
            // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(p.xpoints) + " " +
            // Arrays.toString(p.ypoints));
            g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g.fillPolygon(p);
            placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex);
            p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT + 270),
                    Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 110), nPoints);

            g.drawPolygon(p);
            // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(p.xpoints) + " " +
            // Arrays.toString(p.ypoints));
            g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g.fillPolygon(p);
            placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex);
            // row 3 - five grids
            p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT - 45),
                    Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 200), nPoints);

            g.drawPolygon(p);
            g.setColor(Color.PINK);
            g.fillPolygon(p);
            placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex);
            p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT + 45),
                    Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 200), nPoints);

            g.drawPolygon(p);
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillPolygon(p);
            placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex);
            p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT + 135),
                    Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 200), nPoints);

            g.drawPolygon(p);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillPolygon(p);
            placeNumbers(g, p, !isValidHex);
            p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT + 225),
                    Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 200), nPoints);

            g.drawPolygon(p);
            g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            g.fillPolygon(p);
            placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex);
            p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT + 315),
                    Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 200), nPoints);

            g.drawPolygon(p);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillPolygon(p);
            placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex);
            // row 4 - four grids
            p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT + 0),
                    Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 290), nPoints);

            g.drawPolygon(p);
            g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            g.fillPolygon(p);
            placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex);
            p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT + 90),
                    Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 290), nPoints);

            g.drawPolygon(p);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillPolygon(p);
            placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex);
            p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT + 180),
                    Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 290), nPoints);

            g.drawPolygon(p);
            g.setColor(Color.PINK);
            g.fillPolygon(p);
            placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex);
            p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT + 270),
                    Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 290), nPoints);

            g.drawPolygon(p);
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillPolygon(p);
            placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex);
            // row 5 - three grids
            p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT + 45),
                    Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 380), nPoints);

            g.drawPolygon(p);
            g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g.fillPolygon(p);
            placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex);
            p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT + 135),
                    Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 380), nPoints);

            g.drawPolygon(p);
            g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
            g.fillPolygon(p);
            placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex);
            p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT + 225),
                    Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 380), nPoints);

            g.drawPolygon(p);
            g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            g.fillPolygon(p);
            placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex);
            // repaint();
            return g;
        }

    }
```

Comment: `hexValueList.remove(0);` ← Delete that line.  You should never change state in a paint method which is defined outside of a paint method.  Painting is triggered by the system and can happen for many reasons, sometimes several times per second.  If you want to remove values from that list, do it outside of the paint method (and the methods it calls), then call `repaint()` to make use of the updated list.

Comment: Please be clear. Even though I have added the g.drawString within the paint() method also it keeps on repainting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not modify your `hexValueList` list while painting.

A program does not decide when a component’s paint method is called.  The system is in control of that.

Your paint method can be called for many different reasons, all beyond your control.  Some possible reasons are:

- User moves the window
- User iconifies or deiconifies the window
- User moves another window in front of your window
- User brings your window to the front
- User moves the mouse over your component
- User locks or blanks the screen
- User scrolls the web page containing the applet
- User reloads the web page containing the applet

It is possible for painting to occur many times per second.  Or, it may occur only occasionally.

Since you have no control over the timing of calls to your paint method, you must only have drawing logic in it.  If you remove values from a List, those values won’t be available during subsequent calls to the paint method.

This is why you must not modify your `hexValueList` list in the `placeNumbers` method, since that method is called by `drawHexagonalGrid` which is called by `paint`.

Instead of removing numbers from `hexValueList`, iterate through it, using that List’s [iterator()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#iterator%28%29) method, and pass each iterated int value as a parameter to `placeNumbers`:

```
private void placeNumbers(Graphics g, Polygon p, boolean flag, int hexValue) {
    int x = p.getBounds().x + 30;
    int y = p.getBounds().y + 50;
    int width = p.getBounds().width / 3;
    int height = p.getBounds().width / 3;
    g.drawOval(x, y, width, height);
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    // g.setColor(new Color((int)(Math.random() * 0x1000000)));
    g.fillOval(x, y, width, height);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    if (flag) {
        g.drawString("" + hexValue, x + 10, y + 20);
    }
}

private Graphics drawHexagonalGrid() {
    Iterator<Integer> hexValueIterator = hexValueList.iterator();

    System.out.println("Drawing the hexagonal grid");
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    System.out.println("graphics---->" + g);
    boolean isValidHex = true;
    // row 1 - three grids
    Polygon p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT + 45),
            Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 20), nPoints);
    //
    g.drawPolygon(p);
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillPolygon(p);
    placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex, hexValueIterator.next());
    p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT + 135),
            Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 20), nPoints);

    g.drawPolygon(p);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillPolygon(p);
    placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex, hexValueIterator.next());
    p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT + 225),
            Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 20), nPoints);

    g.drawPolygon(p);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillPolygon(p);
    placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex, hexValueIterator.next());
    // row 2 - four grids
    p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT + 0),
            Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 110), nPoints);

    g.drawPolygon(p);
    // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(p.xpoints) + " " +
    // Arrays.toString(p.ypoints));
    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    g.fillPolygon(p);
    placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex, hexValueIterator.next());
    p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT + 90),
            Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 110), nPoints);

    g.drawPolygon(p);
    // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(p.xpoints) + " " +
    // Arrays.toString(p.ypoints));
    g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
    g.fillPolygon(p);
    placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex, hexValueIterator.next());
    p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT + 180),
            Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 110), nPoints);

    g.drawPolygon(p);
    // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(p.xpoints) + " " +
    // Arrays.toString(p.ypoints));
    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g.fillPolygon(p);
    placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex, hexValueIterator.next());
    p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT + 270),
            Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 110), nPoints);

    g.drawPolygon(p);
    // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(p.xpoints) + " " +
    // Arrays.toString(p.ypoints));
    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g.fillPolygon(p);
    placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex, hexValueIterator.next());
    // row 3 - five grids
    p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT - 45),
            Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 200), nPoints);

    g.drawPolygon(p);
    g.setColor(Color.PINK);
    g.fillPolygon(p);
    placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex, hexValueIterator.next());
    p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT + 45),
            Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 200), nPoints);

    g.drawPolygon(p);
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillPolygon(p);
    placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex, hexValueIterator.next());
    p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT + 135),
            Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 200), nPoints);

    g.drawPolygon(p);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillPolygon(p);
    placeNumbers(g, p, !isValidHex, 0);
    p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT + 225),
            Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 200), nPoints);

    g.drawPolygon(p);
    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    g.fillPolygon(p);
    placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex, hexValueIterator.next());
    p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT + 315),
            Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 200), nPoints);

    g.drawPolygon(p);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillPolygon(p);
    placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex, hexValueIterator.next());
    // row 4 - four grids
    p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT + 0),
            Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 290), nPoints);

    g.drawPolygon(p);
    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    g.fillPolygon(p);
    placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex, hexValueIterator.next());
    p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT + 90),
            Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 290), nPoints);

    g.drawPolygon(p);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillPolygon(p);
    placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex, hexValueIterator.next());
    p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT + 180),
            Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 290), nPoints);

    g.drawPolygon(p);
    g.setColor(Color.PINK);
    g.fillPolygon(p);
    placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex, hexValueIterator.next());
    p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT + 270),
            Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 290), nPoints);

    g.drawPolygon(p);
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillPolygon(p);
    placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex, hexValueIterator.next());
    // row 5 - three grids
    p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT + 45),
            Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 380), nPoints);

    g.drawPolygon(p);
    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g.fillPolygon(p);
    placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex, hexValueIterator.next());
    p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT + 135),
            Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 380), nPoints);

    g.drawPolygon(p);
    g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
    g.fillPolygon(p);
    placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex, hexValueIterator.next());
    p = new Polygon(Utilities.getMoreXPoints(xPoints, HEX_CONSTANT + 225),
            Utilities.getMoreYPoints(yPoints, (HEX_CONSTANT / 9) + 380), nPoints);

    g.drawPolygon(p);
    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    g.fillPolygon(p);
    placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex, hexValueIterator.next());
    // repaint();
    return g;
}
```

Now the painting logic only reads `hexValueList`, without modifying it, so it won’t matter how often the `paint` method is called.

I also removed `flag = false;` since it has no purpose.  `flag` is a method parameter, so changing its value inside the method has no effect outside of the method.

Comment: Thanks i just changed two lines: placeNumbers(g, p, isValidHex, hexValueIterator.next()); and passed the value to placeNumbers and printed g.drawString("" + value, x + 10, y + 20);